# Getting information (types, values...etc) on members of C type struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct, member

I would like to get some help on C-style struct. I do not have much understanding in C so I am not familiar with the basics.

Right now, I have a struct (outerStruct) that has other structs as members (innerStruct1, innerStruct2...). What I need to do is to get values of MEMBER VARIABLES OF innerStruct1, innerStruct2....

The only information I have is the pointer to outerStruct and a data structure that has all the possible variable types of MEMBER VARIABLES OF EACH innerStructs. Note that all the variable names are just variable type 
 + "_val" so if I can types of member variables, I will be able to get variable names as well.

I need to get the information on the MEMBERS OF the innerStructs and parse them into a text file, s.t variable name and variable value would show up.

Can I get the member variable of the innerStruct without using variable names? Since C plays with the memory allocation, maybe this is possible? If this is not possible, what are possible information that I can get?

The container of variable names and types is quite large so if I use all values to retrieve information, it will do too many null checks, and the time will be linear to the size of the container. Instead, I would like to know if I can take advantage of the naming convention and make the code more efficient.

```
struct outerStruct {
   innerStruct1 innerStruct1_val;
   innerStruct2 innerStruct2_val;
}

struct innerStruct1 {
   int int_val = 5;
   char char_val = 'a';
}

struct innerStruct2 {
   float float_val = 4.0;
   double double_val = 5.0;
}
```

Expected output(print to screen):

```
"innerStruct1_val : int_val = 5, char_val = 'a' || innerStruct2_val : float_val = 4.0, double_val = 5.0"
```

TL;DR I want to get values of the inner struct from a nested struct without using the actual variable names.

(Also, the code is here to only show the lay out of the structure. Correct syntax will be used.)

Comment: TL;DR but I can see in your code `outerStruct` is declared before `innerStruct`, also missing `;`'s, and also can't initialize in declarations so this code won't compile

Comment: It sounds like you want to dynamically determine member names at runtime, but C has no runtime introspection capabilities.  Typical implementations don't use type or member names at runtime for any purpose.  References to members are evaluated by the compiler.

Comment: @bigwillydos Hi, I was bit careless on the actual code itself because I did not want to disclose the full information. Given that the code is only there to 'show' how the structure is laid out, do you think you can give your thoughts on this question? Also I added TL;DR for this question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Ok, then for such structure, will I have to specifically call member variables with the correct name in order to get any information?

Comment: Suppose you contrive to access the member without actually usuing its name, is this intended to obfuscate the code? How will anyone reading the code know what its purpose is?

Comment: @WeatherVane The main purpose is to print out the values so it can be read-only. Since the variable naming convention follows a strict rule in relation to the data type, will there be a chance to get the variable type so that I can use it to get the variable names& values?

Comment: There isn't any way in C to iterate through the members of a `struct`, whether or not it has nested `struct` members. One way though, if there is a fixed scheme, is to generate source code with the relevant names and compile it.

Comment: For your purposes, @Anaguone, I think yes, you'll need to refer to members by their names.  There are other potential alternatives, but they require even more information than the names and types of the members of each structure type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C, you have to manually walk the members of respective structures. But, even if you want to keep the structure internals "private", by only making the structure tag name public, you can provide a public function to print the function.

```
struct outerStruct;

void print_outerStruct(const struct outerStruct *);
```

Likewise for the innter structures.

Since you have to define the complete outer structure someplace for it to be useful, that place would also be the place to provide the implementation of its print function.

```
struct outerStruct {
   struct innerStruct1 innerStruct1_val;
   struct innerStruct2 innerStruct2_val;
};

void print_outerStruct (const struct outerStruct *os) {
    printf("outerStruct (%p) { ", os);
    printf("%s: ", "innerStruct1_val");
    print_innerStruct1(&os->innerStruct1_val);
    printf("%s: ", "innerStruct2_val");
    print_innerStruct2(&os->innerStruct2_val);
    printf(" }\n");
}
```

With sufficient scaffolding, you may be able to generate these print functions mechanically. For example, it might require writing a parser for your structures.